# Could not resolve CSS

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm learning NativeScript and following the guides here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling.
But i cannot seems to get the platform specific CSS working, I got the error **"Error: Could not resolve app.component.common.css. Looked for: /data/data/org.nativescript.portalestapp/files/app/app.component.common.css."** when running the code.

I have my files like this:

[image]

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: "ns-app",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "app.component.html",
styleUrls: ["app.component.css"]
})
```

app.component.common.css

```
.page{
background-color: #F4F5F7;
font-family:Poppins-Regular, Poppins
}
```

app.component.android.css

```
@import './app.component.common.css';

.page {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Im following the guide exactly but im not sure where i did wrong.

Comment: try to make your styleUrls: `[ './app.component.css' ]` (relative path). Otherwise, rename your common.css to `app.common.css`

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks for the response. One question, i thought if we use moduleId then the ./ is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I change '@import './app.component.common.css'; to @import '/app.component.common.css'; and it works. I'm not sure why